# Processing parallel requests to a stored procedure synchronously

Tags: database, stored-procedures, concurrency, oracle-sqldeveloper, transaction-isolation

I have a requirement where I need to process parallel (concurrent) requests to a stored procedure synchronously. Let's say if there are 2 requests coming in parallel to execute a stored procedure, the 2nd or 1st request has to wait until the other finishes.

I'm writing stored procedure in following way:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

<My SQL Query here>

COMMIT TRANSACTION 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

Will this work to fulfill my requirement? Or is it that one of the requests will fail due to locks being not held and I would need to retry the failed request? I'm not an expert in SQL or stored procedures. Please suggest. Also, if the above query doesn't work, please suggest how do I achieve it.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: We're using Oracle, updated tags